# What is an automated vent valve?

Tags: condensed-matter, experimental-physics, vacuum, research-level

I was inquiring a company about an air-cooled turbo-molecular pump, and the company asked me whether I used an **automated vent valve**.

- What does automated vent valve mean and do?
- How does it relate to the context of a turbo-molecular pump?

Comment: Question (3) does not seem to be about physics, so I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

First time using a turbo pump I presume.

As one example, [the Varian Turbo-V Vent Device](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjdosXs9LrvAhUQHc0KHdTaDJgQFjAFegQICRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.agilent.com%2Fcs%2Flibrary%2Fusermanuals%2FPublic%2FTurbo-V%2520Vent%2520Device%2520User%2520Manual.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2I7560Lejbfvqaem42M54f) tells you what you want to know:

> The Turbo-V vent device, consisting of a vent control unit and a vent
> valve, is a complete unit suitable for automatic venting of the Turbo-V
> pump when it is switched off or during a power failure switch...

and

> The Turbo-V pump must be vented when it is shut down to prevent
> the forepump oil from contaminating the Turbo-V and the connected
> chamber.

Basically, you don't want the nice vacuum inside the turbo sucking oil out of the backing/roughing/fore pump if the turbo isn't working.